# WebService response is truncated - ASP.NET 4.0

Tags: asp.net, xml, web-services, c#-4.0, load-balancing

I have a web service method, it returns an array of strings. Then if array length is greater than X strings (I suppose the xml response contains 200 or 300 chars) the response is truncated.

However, if the response contains a few strings the response is received fine.

I am hosting this web services in a CMS named `IAPPS`. .NET Framework used is 4.0.

Web service code:

```
[WebMethod]
public String[] getArray() {

    return new string[] { 
                           "My_String",
                           "My_String",
                           "My_String",
                           "My_String",
                           "My_String",
                           "My_String",
                           "My_String"};
}
```

Example of response not truncated:

```
<ArrayOfString xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="My_WebServices">
   <string>My_String</string>
   <string>My_String</string>
   <string>My_String</string>
   <string>My_String</string>
   <string>My_String</string>
   <string>My_String</string>
   <string>My_String</string>
   <string>My_String</string>
   <string>My_String</string>
</ArrayOfString>
```

Example of response truncated:

```
<ArrayOfString xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="My_WebServices">
   <string>My_String</string>
   <string>My_String</string>
   <string>My_String</string>
   <string>My_String</string>
   <string>My_String</string>
   <string>My_String</string>
   <string>My_String</string>
   <string>My_String</string>
   <string>My_String</string>
   <string>My_String</string>
   <string>My_String</string>
   <string>My_String</string>
   <string>My_String</string>
   <string>My_String</string>
   <string>My_String</string>
   <string>My_String</string>
   <string>My_String</string>
   <string>My_String</string>
   <string>My_String</string>
   <string>My_String</string>
   <string>My_String</string>
   <string>My_String</string>
   <string>My_String</string>
   <string>My_Str
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you obtain this response? What parties that can possibly truncate the response (which I seriously doubt is what actually happens) are in between your application and the service?

Comment: I obtain the response using Google Chrome and FireFox

Comment: Finally it's solved. The server reponse from load balanced url's doesn't work fine.